# MySQL query on rows, only return row if row item does not exist in other rows

Tags: mysql, sql

```
     ID      stone_free    original_stone_id
   ------- | ---------- | -------------------
     1     |     0      |         1
     2     |     1      |         2
     3     |     1      |         1
```

I would like to **return rows** from the table only if **stone_free equals 0** and there is **no corresponding original_stone_id** in other rows for each row. So for example in the above example row 1 has stone_free as 0 and there is a corresponding original_stone_id in row 3, therefore the query shouldn't return any rows.

In the example below row 1 has stone_free as 0 but there is no corresponding original_stone_id in the other row, therefore the query should return row 1.

```
     ID      stone_free    original_stone_id
   ------- | ---------- |  -------------------
     1     |     0      |         1
     2     |     1      |         2
```

Comment: There is a value for `original_stone_id` in row `1`. Right?

Comment: @JohnTotetWoo Hi John, Yes there is.

Comment: then why would it return a row on your second example? :) you said that you want to return rows where `stone_free = 0` and no value in the `original_stone_id`.

Comment: @JohnTotetWoo I said I want to return rows where stone_free = 0 not stone_free = 1.

Comment: yeah my bad typo error, i edited it already. so in the second example, what row shall it return?

Comment: @JohnTotetWoo It's OK, I know what you mean. When I say "no corresponding original_stone_id" I don't mean that there should be "no value" for original_stone_id, I mean that the original_stone_id of row 1 shouldn't be the same in any other rows. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `LEFT JOIN` should do it;

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM Stones a
LEFT JOIN Stones b ON a.ID<>b.ID AND a.original_stone_id = b.original_stone_id
WHERE b.ID IS NULL AND a.stone_free=0
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45ee6/6).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it'll work on MySQL but give a shot to it

```
select  * 
from tbl
where   stone_free = 0 and
     ( 
    select count(tab.original_stone_id) 
    from tbl tab 
    where tab.original_stone_id = tbl.original_stone_id
     ) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from tablename t1
Where stone_free = 0
And Not Exists (Select Id from tablename t2 where t2.original_stone_id = t1.original_stone_id And t2.Id <> t1.Id)
```